# Aurora RDS async replication to historical MySQL cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, amazon-rds-aurora

I was trying to do https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-howto-masterstatus.html until the command to pause all writes gets access denied on my test db

```
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
Error Code 1045. Access denied for user 'admin'@'%'
```

So in Aurora RDS, how do I pause all writes, grab the binary log filename and offset, take snapshot, and then unpause all writes?

Then, I can restore the snapshot, and I hope setup to start replicating from that offset to catch up to the source database.

Comment: For Aurora MySQL or RDS MySQL I would suggest following the steps in the AWS docs rather than in the MySQL official manual. Aurora/RDS MySQL doesn't provide `SUPER` user privileges afaik hence the issue with FTWRL. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.MySQL.html#AuroraMySQL.Replication.MySQL.CreateSnapshot

Comment: thanks, those worked better!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Aurora MySQL or RDS MySQL refer to the [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.MySQL.html#AuroraMySQL.Replication.MySQL.CreateSnapshot) in AWS rather than the MySQL manual. Aurora/RDS MySQL doesn't support `SUPER` privileges hence the issue with FTWRL.

*Added to mark as answer*

Comment: lol, yes, i was like crap, I can't mark a comment as correct and fixed my issue...lol.